# Laravel Eloquent Model Naming Does not Work

Tags: php, laravel

I have model file where I want to define "user_coin" in the relations. However, it does not work.

Result

> null

So, then after debugging it. I found that it works when I named it with "user_coins". Afterwards, the relation works and giving result.

Here is the code model User.php

```
public function user_membership() : HasOne{
    return $this->hasOne(UserMembership::class,'id');
}

public function user_coins() : HasMany{ // Does not work when I define "user_coin"
    return $this->hasMany(UserCoin::class);
}
```

The odd thing, "user_membership" does not use plural and it worked fine.

Model for UserCoins.php

```
class UserCoin extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'coin_id',
        'amount',
    ];

    public function user() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function coin() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(Coin::class);
    }
}
```

Model for UserMembership.php

```
class UserMembership extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'membership_id',
        'expired_at',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'expired_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    public function user() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function membership() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(Membership::class);
    }
}
```

I need to be systematic in programming where it does not use plural to define model function but this one is something weird. I have define many models but never find out something like this.

Comment: [hasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) ->  singular by laravel, [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)-> plural

Comment: hi, the problem only to name the function which I use singular on all model whether it is hasOne or hasMany. If I change it for example to "coin_user". It works, there is only one naming "user_coin" which is not working.

Comment: try overwrite the magic methods in laravel with this `$this->hasMany(UserCoin::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`
ps: `UserCoin` doesn't have a `user_id` in fillable?